# Java : guava Futures API with ListenableFuture

Tags: java, guava, future

I'm trying having a better understanding of guava API with easy example :
First I instantiate ListenableFuture that returns "hello"
Then I use Futures.transform() to transform my "hello" into "HELLO"
But I got no results.

Here is my code (I remove other methods in the ListenableFuture implementation to make things easier) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ListenableFuture<String> future = getString();
        ListenableFuture<String> future2 = Futures.transform(future, new Function<String,String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply(String input) {
                return input.toUpperCase();
            }

        });
        System.out.println(future.get());  //print "hello"
        System.out.println(future2.get());  //blocking, never ends...no result
    }


    private static ListenableFuture<String> getString() {
        return new ListenableFuture<String>() {

            @Override
            public String get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
                return "hello";
            }

        };
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably indicates a bug in those "other methods in the ListenableFuture implementation" that you removed to make things easier.

Instead of implementing your own `ListenableFuture`, use `Futures.immediateFuture("hello")` to get a correct implementation.

Comment: thanks. It works now. Still surprised why my implementation fails because when I do future.get() it works fine and returns "hello" properly

Comment: @AntonBoarf Sure it does.  But the implementation of `Futures.transform` does actually use the `addListener` method, which you omitted.  `addListener` is what makes that method _possible_ in the first place, unlike with normal `Future`s.